# Gesture Animations in Windows Phone 8.1 WinRT

Tags: wpf, animation, windows-runtime, listviewitem, gestures

I'm building an application that will allow the user to swipe on a ListViewItem to perform an action.

I can look at all the articles on the gesture api's online so that's OK - but how would I animate my ListViewItem. So swiping from left to right will move the item to the right and swiping right to left will move the item to the left.

Is there any way to bind the gesture to a visual animation?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the ManipulationMode property to "System,TranslateX", so your ListViewItem can be moved only horizontally. After that, listen to these events: ManipulationStarted, ManipulationDelta and ManipulationCompleted.
I recommend using this structure:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Canvas>
      <Grid></Grid> //the grid will have your content and can be moved
    </Canvas>
  </DataTemplate>
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

In ManipulationStarted, you get the distance that the user swiped with the finger, and move the Grid in the Canvas.
Something like this:

```
 private void GridManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var grid = sender as Grid;

            if ( grid != null )
            {
                var distance = Canvas.GetLeft(grid) + e.Delta.Translation.X;
                //here you should test if the user has swiped too far(outside the screen), and prevent that
                Canvas.SetLeft(grid, distance); //set the grid to the new position inside the canvas
            }
        }
```

I hope this helps. If you have any more questions please let me know.